# Attic space above garage - insulation

Tags: insulation, attic

I am a first-time homeowner, and one of the points in my home inspection report reads:

> Garage: install proper attic hatch doors, weather stripping and
> insulate.

Here is what the garage attic hatches look right now (picture below):

[image]

The previous owner just put fiberglass batts over the hatches. I have the following questions:

1. What are differences in quality standards when it comes insulating living vs non-living spaces (e.g., garage)? If so, what is the proper R value for the garage attic assuming cold climate (Canada, Montana or Minnesota on the US scale).
2. Is the inspector's point necessary  to address?

Appreciate your input.

Comment: Garage insulation is nice if you plan on working in there, having heat/cooling, instead of just jumping in your car.  Hatch doors might needed for fire code(fire/CO blocking/slowing).  Home inspectors do sometimes add stuff to look like they are doing their job, give suggestions,  building inspectors(from town/city) are the ones you need to listen to, or can get fines.

Comment: Is the garage separate from the house, and if not, is the wall between the garage and house insulated as well as the rest of the shell? If not, it might be worth insulating the garage to get your home heating bill down a bit, the more pleasant temperature in winter is an added bonus then.

Comment: @MiG the garage is attached to the house

Comment: And that second question, how well insulated is the wall between the garage and the house?

Comment: @MiG I will check that l, don't have a ladder to get in there:)

Comment: For point 2, the inspector wrote it up to make you aware of the condition of the house to facilitate your purchase.  You bought it despite the inspector's comments (which about 99.99% of people do).  Is it required for you to address those items after you bought it?  Not from the inspector's perspective - he's long gone now.  It's your house, your choice at this point.  So it comes down to what effort versus risk you see in this, with the risks being any potential for fire, flood, high expenses later on, selling the house in the future, or attracting the attention of local building inspectors.

Comment: It's a fire hazard as it sits, for the main thing. If the garage attic is insulated, the cover should also be insulated.

Comment: @Smith This is why I asked the question: to see what risks are eliminated (e.g., fire risk) and what is achieved  (e.g., better insulation -> lower heat bill).

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks for pointing out the fire risk. Is attached garage attic insulation typically required by building codes in North America?

Comment: We often refer to the Local Area Having Jurisdiction - LAHJ. North America has a wide variety of applicable code - you'll need to sort out yours because that's the one that matters to exactly where you are, and it can be different in the next town over. Model codes are often adopted with local changes, or years late. On the whole, if the garage is heated or cooled you'll definitely want it, regardless of code. It can help even if the garage is not actively heated or cooled, by moderating the rate at which it heats or cools in response to the outside temperature and sun.

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks for your input. I am a new home owner and am trying to learn as much as possible. Also, the fact that I grew up in Europe doesn't help, because houses there are typically built in a completely different fashion so my prior knowledge doesn't help at all.